# share application link in uri

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

Is it possible to re-write this share application link using uri for a case switch?

```
         try
      { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
  i.setType("text/plain");
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
  String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
  sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Orion.Soft \n\n";
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);  
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
  }
 catch(Exception e)
 { //e.toString();
}
```

example

```
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_share:
    ...
```

Comment: What do you mean a case switch? Please explain your issue better

Comment: I want to write the first set of code using uri . It will be in the onOptionsItemSelected class as shown. (I added code)

Comment: You are already using an URI as a String. Just move the code to onOptionsItemSelected() method